# How to determine the size of an input argument for a function handle

Tags: matlab

I am creating a function that takes in data (`x,y,z`) and an anonymous function (`M`) as inputs. `M`'s inputs are data (`x,y,z`) and a parameter (`theta`).

I need to determine the dimension of the parameter `theta` inside `FUNC`

**EDIT:** (To add some context)

I have data that follows a known data generating process (DGP). For example, I can generate data using a linear instrumental variable DGP with 1 endogenous variable (hence `theta` will be dimension 1):

```
n = 100; q = 10;
theta0 = 1;                               % true param value
e = randn(n, 1);                          % 2nd stage error
u = randn(n, 1);                          % 1st stage error
z = randn(n, q);                          % instrument
x = z * ones(q, 1) + u;                   % endog variable
y = x * theta0 + e;                       % dependent variable
```

Then I want to estimate `theta0` using my own variation of generalized linear methods (`FUNC`)

```
M = @(x,y,z,theta) z' * (y - x * theta);  % moment condition
thetahat = FUNC(M, x, y, z);              % estimate theta0
```

and `FUNC.m` is

```
function out = FUNC(M, x, y, z)
k = ; % (!!!) <-- this is what I need to find out!
objFunc = @(theta) M(x, y, z, theta)' * M(x, y, z, theta);
out = fminunc(objFunc, ones(1, k)); % <-- this is where its used
end
```

---

In the above example, the DGP is a linear IV model. However, I should be able to use my function for any other DGP.

Other DGPs could, for example, define `M` as follows:

```
% E.g. 1) theta is dimension 1
M=@(x,y,z,theta) z' * (y - x * theta); 
% E.g. 2) theta is dimension 2
M=@(x,y,z,theta) z' * (y - (x * theta(1))^theta(2)); 
% E.g. 3) theta is dimension 3
M=@(x,y,z,theta) z' * (y - (theta(1) + x * theta(2))^theta(3));
```

---

The (super bad) hack that I am currently using for `(!!!)` is:

```
for ktest = [3,2,1] % the dimension of theta will never be higher than 3
    try 
        M(x, y, z, ones(1, ktest);
        k = ktest;     
    end
end
```

Comment: This looks like an interesting question, but I don't get it. Is `theta` defined within `FUNC`? When is `M` defined? Please post a complete example

Comment: @LuisMendo edited. Hope this is clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB doesn't store any information about the size of the inputs to an anonymous function. While a better idea would be to modify your code so you don't have to do these kinds of gymnastics, if your function definition is known to fit a narrow band of possibilities you could use a regular expression to parse the function definition itself. You can get this string from the return of [`functions`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/functions.html).

For example:

```
function [nelements] = findsizetheta(fh)
defstr = func2str(fh);
test = regexp(defstr, 'theta\((\d+)\)', 'tokens');

if isempty(test)
    % Assume we have theta instead of theta(1)
    nelements = 1;
else
    nelements = max(str2double([test{:}]));
end
end
```

Which returns `1`, `2`, and `3` for your example definitions of `M`.

This assumes that `theta` is present in you anonymous function and that it is defined as a vector.

Also note that MATLAB cautions against utilizing `functions` in a programmatic manner, as its behavior may change in future releases. This was tested to function in R2017b.

Comment: You can directly apply `str2double`. No need of `cellfun`

Comment: You can also just use [`func2str`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/func2str.html) like so: `defstr = func2str(fh);`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you know already what the form and requirements of your function `M` will be when you pass it to `FUNC`, it doesn't make much sense to then require `FUNC` to determine it based only on `M`. It would make much more sense to pass flag values or needed information to `FUNC` when you pass it `M`. I would write `FUNC` in one of two ways:

```
function out = FUNC(M, x, y, z, k)  % Accept k as an argument
  ...
end

function out = FUNC(M, x, y, z, theta0)  % Pass the initial guess, of the correct size
  ...
end
```

If you *really* want to let `FUNC` do the extra work, then [the answer from excaza](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47144605/52738) is how I would do it.

---

*Old answer below. not really valid since the question was clarified, but I'm leaving it temporarily...*

I think you have two better options here...

### Make `M` a cell array of anonymous functions:

You could make your input `M` a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) of possible [anonymous functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) and use the number of values in `theta` as the index. You would pass this `M` to `FUNC`:

```
M = {@(x,y,z,theta) z' * (y - x * theta), ...
     @(x,y,z,theta) z' * (y - (x * theta(1))^theta(2)), ...
     @(x,y,z,theta) z' * (y - (theta(1) + x * theta(2))^theta(3))};
```

Then somewhere inside `FUNC`:

```
out = M{numel(theta)}(x, y, z, theta);
```

### Make `M` a normal function instead of an anonymous one:

An [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) is good for quick, simple formulas. Add in conditional logic and you should probably just make it a fully-fledged [function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html). Here's an example with a switch statement (good for if you have a number of different formulas):

```
function out = M(x, y, x, theta)
  switch numel(theta)
    case 1
      out = z' * (y - x * theta);
    case 2
      out = z' * (y - (x * theta(1))^theta(2));
    case 3
      out = z' * (y - (theta(1) + x * theta(2))^theta(3));
  end
end
```

And here's an example that sets some defaults for parameters (good for if you have one formula with different ways to set its parameters, like you seem to have):

```
function out = M(x, y, x, theta)
  switch numel(theta)
    case 1
      p1 = 0;
      p2 = theta;
      p3 = 1;
    case 2
      p1 = 0;
      p2 = theta(1);
      p3 = theta(2);
    case 3
      p1 = theta(1);
      p2 = theta(2);
      p3 = theta(3);
  end
  out = z' * (y - (p1 + x * p2)^p3);
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not mean to imply that I am using all 3 `M` functions simultaneously, but I rather meant to say that my function `FUNC` should be general and not use a hardcoded example of `M`. I edited the question, hope its clearer.

Comment: Initially, I had the function require an initial guess for `theta0` but I was told (from above) to reduce the inputs to `M,x,y,z`.

Comment: @greyBag: In that case, I'd probably piggyback on the `M` input by making it a cell array `{M k}` or `{M theta0}`, but I'm sneaky like that. ;)